# Setting field read-only depending on errors

Tags: xpages

I have few components- combo boxes, edit boxes and error messages.

What I'm trying to do is to make combo box read only if the error message (that is attached to the edit box) contains something.

I'm trying to use this in the "read-only" computed field:

```
getComponent("message3").value == ""
```

Apparently i'm doing something wrong and it throws error when I load the xpage. Any advice how to achieve the functionality I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following to check for error messages:

```
facesContext.getMessages().hasNext()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As far as I understand- does this check for all the error messages in the xpage? If so this solution will not work for what I intend to do...

Comment: My bad, I guess it actually does what I need. The problem is with something else that I have in my xpage, thanks for the answer.